# How to find the NAME of the sequence used for native generator class in hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am supporting a Java-Hibernate-Oracle based system that contains the following definition for the ID column (primary key) in it `hbm.xml` file:

```
    <id name="id" type="long" column="ID">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
```

If I were to write myself, I would have probably included an explicit `<param name="sequence">` to self-document my code to point at the actual sequence name.

But I inherited this code and I am not sure whether there is an implied SEQUENCE name associated with the implied sequence in this concise directive (probably using defaults).

Is there a way to find out what the name of that sequence is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Oracle dialect if you don't set the name of the sequence, Hibernate will use `HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE` by default.